# Facebook session query

Tags: php, facebook

Since I have just started working with Facebook's api I had a few questions regarding Facebook sessions. In the index of my iFrame app I have the user establish a new sessions and set the $me and $uid variables as displayed in their [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php).

However, when my app navigates to a new page should I create a new session and redeclare these variables or is there some way to grab those values from the already declared session?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid facebook API call as much as possible.

```
session_start();
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
$_SESSION['user'] = $me;

print_r($_SESSION['user']);
```

as long as user not log out you can use this session. make sure destroy the `$_SESSION['user']` on `$facebook->getLogoutUrl()`